# Monitor Windows 7 Performance Counters from Server 2012

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, perfmon

I want to monitor performance counters on my Windows 7 Machines from Windows Server 2012.

Right now, I have two Windows 7 machines that can monitor each other's performance counters no problem.  To allow access, I have started the Remote Registry service and added Everyone to the Performance Log Users and Performance Monitor Users groups.

The problem is, if I try to add performance counters from either of these machines in Server 2012, I get the error message "Unable to connect to machine".  The Windows 7 machines show up under the search and their names check out, but I am unable to get a listing of the counters.  I have disabled the firewall on the Windows 7 machines for good measure, but still have the same results.

Does anyone know if I can monitor Windows 7 performance counters from Server 2012 or have any insight into the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing Management Framework 3.0 on your Windows 7 machine:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595

Edit: Make sure to enable remote management on your Win 7 machine afterwards with `enable-psremoting`.